# How to pass value from Activity to Widget use Intent action extra

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-widget, android-broadcast, appwidgetprovider

I would like pass an value to my widget using Intent. But something wrong, I can not receive my intent extra value..

My MainActivity:

```
 var testValue = "test"
        val intent = Intent("my.action.string")
        intent.putExtra("extra", testValue)
        sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Manifest:

```
     <receiver
                android:name=".ui.widget.RateWidget"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                    <action android:name="my.action.string" />
                </intent-filter>
    
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/rate_widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

My Widget class:

```
class RateWidget: AppWidgetProvider() {

    private var myMessage = "default"

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)

        val action = intent?.action

        if (action == "my.action.string") {
            val state = intent.extras!!.getString("extra")
            if (state != null) {
                myMessage = state
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in widget:

```
val state = intent.getStringExtra("extra")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).